# TFS 2015 using Visual studio 2008

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I've installed MSSCCI from the below link: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/22d38324-051c-4f04-9379-ff78e7116c8d

After installing, as suggested in this blog(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2014/01/23/connecting-to-team-foundation-server-2013-using-visual-studio-2005-thru-msscci-provider.aspx) I don't see a plugin in the source control dropdown in VS 2008(Tools -> Options->Source Control). Neither I have an option under File-> Source Control to Launch Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider.

Please help.

Comment: I can't resist asking this: Why on Earth would you choose to connect to TFS 2015 with VS 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, be sure that [Team Explorer 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16338) is installed, then install MSSCCI 2013 provider.

Secondly, once the MSSCCI 2013 provider is installed, please restart Visual Studio 2008. Then you should get these options.